# Show retweet counts using Twitter Fabric Android Sdk's TweetViewAdpater

Tags: android, android-layout, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using Twitter's android sdk for developing an app. In the given sdk there is a **CompactTweetView** for displaying the Tweets, but there is no field for showing retweets counts in it. To display the tweets I am using **TweetViewAdapter** provided in sdk.

Now I want to show the retweet counts also below each tweets. How can I achieve my objective ? Do I have to add separate rows after each entry in ListView to show retweet counts or is there any other way by which I can extend the CompactTweetView to include retweet count. Another way is that I use an empty LinearLayout and add a row for retweet count view after each CompactTweetView. What will be the performance in both cases

1. ListView (If possible then how to do it ?)
2. Empty LinearLayout with alternate CompactTweetView and retweet count View.

If anything is not clear please ask for more information. Thanks.

Current state of of my twitter app using ListView with TweetViewAdapter.
I want to display retweet count after each row.
[image]

Comment: I have got the answer. It can be done by extending the TweetViewAdapter and overriding the getView function with required UI elements in it. Thanks.

Comment: and what about click events of those buttons ? Is there fabric api for retweet , favorite and reply , I have to implement it also?

Comment: No, it is already present in fabric api. Use statusesService for different options like retweet, reply favorite etc.
statusesService  = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();

Comment: ok thnx for the help. I suppose it doesn't have reply as it's not documented https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/api

Comment: Can you please upvote my question if it was of any help to you ?

Comment: I also will have to check. I have used only retweets  as of now.

Comment: ok thnx and It'll be great if you have some code sample of this may be on github.

Comment: Yes I will upload it soon. Meanwhile you can also join Twitter community for developers. I got some help from there also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search on fabric iu sdks the tw__tweet_compact.xml or tw__tweet.xml layout.Copy in resources layouts.Don't change the name. Add your custom Texview to show retweets count.
This is my custom tw__tweet_compact.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_view"
style="@style/tw__CompactTweetContainer">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_retweeted_by"
    style="@style/tw__TweetRetweetedBy.Compact"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tw__author_attribution"
    tools:text="retweeted by" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
    style="@style/tw__TweetAvatar.Compact"
    android:layout_below="@id/tw__tweet_retweeted_by"
    tools:background="@color/tw__tweet_media_preview_bg_color"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<!--Name and timestamp don't ellipsize, but @username in the middle does ellipsize-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tw__author_attribution"
    style="@style/tw__CompactAttributionLine"
    android:layout_below="@id/tw__tweet_retweeted_by"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_author_full_name"
        style="@style/tw__TweetFullName.Compact"
        tools:text="Jack" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_author_screen_name"
        style="@style/tw__TweetScreenName.Compact"
        tools:text="@jack" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_timestamp"
        style="@style/tw__TweetTimestamp.Compact"
        tools:text="• 03/21/2006" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tw__twitter_logo"
    style="@style/tw__TwitterLogo.Compact"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tw__tweet_retweeted_by"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.internal.util.AspectRatioImageView
    android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_media"
    style="@style/tw__TweetMedia.Compact"
    android:layout_below="@id/tw__author_attribution"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tw__tweet_text"
    style="@style/tw__TweetText.Compact"
    android:layout_below="@id/tw__tweet_media"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
    tools:text="just setting up my twttr" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rtwfavLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tw__tweet_text"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tw__tweet_author_avatar"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/tw__ic_retweet_light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rtwtxt"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:singleLine="true"


        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/favourite" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/favtxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After modifying your tweet adapter. In the method getView add TextView and set the number of retweets in the TextView. The number of favorites does not work well. Only shows own favorite tweets. Favorite tweets of other users don't displays.

```
 public class TweetAdapter extends TweetTimelineListAdapter {
    public TweetAdapter(Context context, Timeline<Tweet> timeline) {
        super(context, timeline);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        CompactTweetView compactTweetView = (CompactTweetView) view;

        TextView txtfav = (TextView) compactTweetView.findViewById(R.id.favtxt);

    TextView txtrtw = (TextView) compactTweetView.findViewById(R.id.rtwtxt);


    if (compactTweetView.getTweet().retweetedStatus != null) {
        txtfav.setText(String.valueOf(compactTweetView.getTweet().retweetedStatus.favoriteCount));
        if (txtfav.getText().equals("null")) {
            txtfav.setText(String.valueOf(compactTweetView.getTweet().favoriteCount));
        }
        txtrtw.setText(String.valueOf(compactTweetView.getTweet().retweetedStatus.retweetedStatus));
        if (txtrtw.getText().equals("null")) {
            txtrtw.setText(String.valueOf(compactTweetView.getTweet().retweetCount));
        }
    } else {
        txtfav.setText(String.valueOf(compactTweetView.getTweet().favoriteCount));
        txtrtw.setText(String.valueOf(compactTweetView.getTweet().retweetCount));
    }

        return compactTweetView;
    }
}
```

I think this way is easier. Regards