# How to show retweets and like counts in iOS TwitterKit?

Tags: ios, twitter, twitterkit

In twitterKit, there is a `tweetView` for displaying the `Tweet` from tweet model object, but there is no field for showing retweets and likes counts in the tweetView.

```
cell.tweetView.showActionButtons = true;
```

This allow us to show action buttons for favorite and share. But I want to show the retweet/likes counts in each tweets. How can I achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subclass a regular `UITableViewCell` and use a `TWTRTweetView` inside of it. Which is basically what `TWTRTweetTableViewCell` does, it has a tweetView property which is essentially an IBOutlet of type `TWTRTweetView` and use that in the tableview cell instead.

Place the custom label for `like and retweets` counts in proper position on top of the `TWTRTweetView`.

```
- (void)configureCell:(TWTRTweet *)tweet{
  self.customTweetView.showActionButtons = true;
  [self.customTweetView configureWithTweet:tweet];
  self.likesCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", tweet.likeCount];
  self.retweetsCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", tweet.retweetCount];
}
```

For more info: [check this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47615777/3694459)